# Can I estimate the probability of a given output of the diffusion model?

Tags: machine-learning, pr.probability

I have a pretrained Grad-TTS (https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.06337) denoising diffusion model that predicts a spectrogram (an array of numerical values) $Y$ from input text $X$. If I have a text $X_0$ and a spectrogram $Y_0$, can I somehow calculate the probability $P(Y_0|X_0, \theta)$ where $\theta$ is model parameters? In other words, I would like to estimate the probability to get the array as an output if I pass the text to the model. E.g., for an autoregressive model, it would be $\prod P(y_i|y_{j<i}, X, \theta)$. Is there a formula for diffusion models?

Comment: Take a look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.13456.pdf on the part about exact likelihood computation.